# How to properly mock useRef hook with react-testing-library and jest

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-testing-library, ts-jest, use-ref

I am having some problems to properly mock useRef hook in am project I am developing. I am using React with Typescript in my project, and using react testing library and jest to unit test my components.

After going throughout the documentation and a few blog posts, I am still unsure why I am unable to make it work correctly as it seems a fairly simple case. I have isolated the problem in a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/late-cookies-myz8g5?file=/src/__tests__/UseRefTest.test.tsx:0-875).

This would be the main component of my example to replicate the problem. I simply have a button that executes a method implemented in the referenced component and the referenced component itself to which I pass the ref.

```
import { useRef } from "react";
import ReferencedComponent, { References } from "./ReferencedComponent";

export default function UseRefTest() {
  const refApiCallUiFeedback = useRef<References>(null);
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => refApiCallUiFeedback.current?.ReferencedMethod()}>
        BUTTON
      </button>
      <ReferencedComponent ref={refApiCallUiFeedback} />
    </>
  );
}
```

This is the actual "ReferencedComponent". It is a dummy component containing a method which is exposed via "useImperativeHandle"

```
import React, { Ref, useImperativeHandle } from "react";

export interface References {
  ReferencedMethod: () => void;
}

function ReferencedComponentWrapped(empty: {}, ref: Ref<References>) {
  function ReferencedMethod() {
    console.log("Calling real referenced method");
  }

  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    ReferencedMethod
  }));

  return (
    <>
      <div>Referenced Component</div>
    </>
  );
}

const ReferencedComponent = React.forwardRef(ReferencedComponentWrapped);

export default ReferencedComponent;
```

Finally this it the unit test in which I simply fire the click event and expect the method to be called.

```
import React, { RefObject } from "react";
import { render, fireEvent, screen } from "@testing-library/react";

import UseRefTest from "../UseRefTest";
import { References } from "../ReferencedComponent";

describe("Testing if useRef Mocking", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {});

  afterEach(() => {
    jest.restoreAllMocks();
    jest.resetAllMocks();
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });

  test("is working as expected", async () => {
    //ARRANGE
    const mockReferencedMethod = jest.fn(() =>
      console.log("Calling mocked referenced method")
    );

    const refs: RefObject<References> = {
      current: { ReferencedMethod: mockReferencedMethod }
    };

    jest.spyOn(React, "useRef").mockReturnValue(refs);

    render(<UseRefTest />);

    //ACT
    fireEvent.click(screen.getByRole("button"));

    //ASSERT
    expect(mockReferencedMethod).toBeCalled();
  });
});
```

You can find here the full working example -> [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/late-cookies-myz8g5?file=/src/__tests__/UseRefTest.test.tsx:0-875)

Comment: The recommended way is **do not** mock `useRef` and anything from third-party packages. You should test the component behavior rather than the implementation details. Assert some method to be called is testing the implementation details. You should test when the `ReferencedMethod` function is called, and what happens to your component such as UI changes. What user can see on the screen?

Comment: Thank you for your help @slideshowp2. I understand your point and most likely this could be a solution for my use case. However, what if there was an use case in which the referenced method does not produce any UI visible change and whatever is being done by the method has already been unit tested in the referenced component? And then, imagine the method is being conditionally called by the hosting component, shouldn´t you test whether the method is being called or not in order to have a reasonable coverage?